# Heroku Flask .json() not working 500 error

Tags: flask, heroku

I have searched about this problem on stackoverflow 20 times at least. Here's my code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
import requests

@app.route("/test")
def test():
    agent = {"User-Agent":'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.87 Safari/537.36'}
    url = 'https://www.nseindia.com/api/quote-equity'
    params = dict()
    params["symbol"] = 'ESCORTS'

    req = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=agent)
    data = req.json()
    return data
```

Heroku Logs:

```
2020-09-14T15:38:41.158156+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/test" host=insider-india.herokuapp.com request_id=07d0c887-62f4-4046-a042-add6bee716bf fwd="182.64.176.133" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30002ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=http
```

If I instead comment out `data=req.json()` and `return req`, It would work. Why doesn't heroku support `requests.json()`? And if it does, how to make it work?

And everything works perfectly fine with localhost (on my machine), it seems like Heroku issue.

Comment: You probably meant to do `return jsonify(data)`

Comment: @TinNguyen But it's working locally.